# How can I speech enhancement with DNN?

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, speech, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to do speech enhancement with DNN on Matlab. I downloaded the TIMIT dataset from the internet as a .wav file. I also downloaded the noises from the Noisex-92 database as .m file. Now I need to add noise to clean speechs. But I don't know how to start the code. How do I add noise to clean speech? After this step I need to extract features for DNN. But I can't find any sample code. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps start [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.08625.pdf).

Comment: The paper by @PeterK. is called [Noisy Target Training: A Training Strategy for DNN-based Speech Enhancement without Clean Speech](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.08625).